# Верстка письма для gmail,как убрать дефолтные margin-block?

Tags: html, css, margin

при создании письма столкнулся с трудностями ,в отличие от других почтовых клиентов,в которых все отображается корректно . Письмо приходящее на gmail не имеет свойств margin-block которые были переданы при разработке

```
(значение 0 меняется на 

margin-block-start: 1em;
margin-block-end: 1em;

)
```

пример стилей из gmail
[image: пример стилей из gmail]